# Using pysaprk got pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: mismatched input 'OFFSET' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}( error

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark

I am using spark SQL in pyspark for some SQL query in MYSQL DB:

```
output = scSpark.sql('SELECT Categories AS type, `Course Material Title` AS title, `Author/Editor` AS author, `iSBN` AS isbn,  `Publication Year` AS pub_date, `edition` AS edition, `e-iSBN / VBID` AS vbid,  `Distribution Mode` AS Distribution_platform FROM books LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1')
```

I got the error when using this SQL query:
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:
mismatched input 'OFFSET' expecting {, ';'}(line 1, pos 249)

How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL `limit` clause has no `offset` option. Details can be found at:
[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-limit.html)

Comment: Then how could I remove the first row in pyspark SQL? thanks